# SQLDependencyEx TableChanged Event

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldependency

I would like to start by saying I have researched over and over and have read most of  the dyatchenko posts.

I can't seem to get the event to fire when new data are inserted into the DB table.

SQL Connection String:

```
 "Server=Server\\instance;DataBase=SQLDependencyExTest;User Id=User;Password=Password;
```

> SQL Database name: "SQLDependencyExTest"
>  Table name: "dbo.Names"
>   (ID int, Names nvarchar(50))

Created a new project added "SqlDependencyEx.cs".

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(connectionstr, "SQLDependencyExTest", "dbo.Names");

        sqlDependency.TableChanged += Changed;
        sqlDependency.Start();

    }

    private void Changed(object sender, SqlDependencyEx.TableChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do stuff from e.Data
        MessageBox.Show("Fired");
    }
```

I placed a Breakpoint in `Changed` sub, it never fires.

If anyone could point me to whatever I am doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable the broker service at your database server?

Comment: Yes I have enabled it.

Comment: Is that a webform? You should start your dependency on the global asax class

Comment: Did you set the `CommandText` property of the `SqlCommand` parameter?

Comment: Tavitos - It's a winform.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - SQLDependencyEx is created by dyatchenko at [link](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/README.md), I followed instructions as specified, still not working.

Comment: Although it says alter authorization is for sqlexpress, you should give authorization for other versions as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem.
I deleted the database and recreated it, problem solved.
Thanks to all who tried to help.